# How to create a layer (with opacity) on above an image?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How can we create the effect as shown in below image?

[image: What I need to create]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/#article-header-id-6 it is opacity or brightness, but if you need it at only part of the image, you need make an overlay from transparent image or div, that combined together makes the effect.

Comment: You may find your answer here: [css transparent shape over image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816362/css-transparent-shape-over-image)

Answer (score 2):

This overlay can be created with `:before` or `:after` pseudo element:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image-holder">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/waDgcnc.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Necessary CSS:**

```
.image-holder {
  position: relative;
}
.image-holder:before {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 20%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
.image-holder {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-holder:before {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 20%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.image-holder img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/waDgcnc.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This effect can also be achieved using css-blend-modes. This allows you to change the effect.

```
.image {
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/enR1O5/bg.jpg);
  height: 320px;
  width: 512px;
  position: relative;
}

.image:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/enR1O5/bg.jpg);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](https://codepen.io/2ne/pen/vmZXxX)

Answer (score 1):

```css
div.background {
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/enR1O5/bg.jpg") repeat;
 width:100%
}

div.transbox {

  background-color: #ffffff;

  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 width:30%;
 Height:300px;
}

div.transbox p {

  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="background">
  <div class="transbox">
    <p>Transparent part.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you answer yourself in a minute?

Comment: so did you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution [Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/SHABU89/w5jbxd0k/)

```
<div class="img-background">
<div class="img-transparent">
</div>
</div>
.img-background{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  background-image:url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg");
  height:400px;
}
.img-transparent
{
  background-color:#fff;
  width:20%;
  float:left;
   height:400px;
   opacity:0.5;
z-index:1;
}
```